# WHERE rows in col1 that are present as a substring of col2 in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have two columns in separate tables structured as follows.

table1.col1: Rows are one word strings.
table2.col2: Rows are many word strings.

I would like to `SELECT` all the rows of col1 that are present as a substring of any row in col2.

For example I would want to keep the row containing "fox" in table1.col1 if any rows in table2.col2 have the string "the quick brown fox", but remove the row containing "xyz" if it is not present in any rows in table2.col2.

I know you can use `LIKE` to compare to one string, but not sure how to compare to a column of strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` could be used at `JOIN` condition level:

```
SELECT * 
       -- DISTINCT table1.*  -- if only rows from table1 are required
FROM table2 -- many words string
JOIN table1 -- single terms
  ON table2.col2 ILIKE CONCAT('%', table1.col1, '%');
```